# Java- toCharArray() method

Tags: java

```
Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
int len=in.nextInt();
String s=in.next();
char[] ch=s.toCharArray();
System.out.println(len);
System.out.println(ch.length);
```

I have run this code snippet by providing input

```
400004
//and a string of length 400004
```

The output was

```
400004
8190
```

I know when we use toCharArray() then it returns a char array having same length as of the String. But here it is diffirentcult.
I am not able to understand how this is possile.
Please help me out here.

Comment: why not use `s.length()`?

Comment: Did the string have whitespace in it?

Comment: Try to use the debugger. It will show you what the array looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly copied and pasted a string that contains a newline character or another character, which made the `next` method of `Scanner` return. Thus, only part of the string is copied to `s`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code, only length = 8190 string is entered in String variable because of constraint of command prompt buffer.

You can try getting input from a text file, it works.

See me code billow for reference.

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);        
    int n=0;
    String number=null;  
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txt file path"));

        String len= br.readLine();
        n=Integer.parseInt(len);
        number = br.readLine();
       }
 catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```